# MySQL InnoDB Disk Writes increase suddenly after 2.5 hours

Tags: mysql, database, performance, innodb

MySQL version = 5.7.31

We started noticing high CPU utilization in our DB server after 2.5 hours of heavy work load (roughly 800 selects per second). DB was performing quite well, and all of a sudden InnoDB Disk Writes increase significantly, followed by InnoDB Disk Reads. Select count drops to zero at this point making the application useless.
After about 15 mins the DB starts working normally.
[image: mysql work bench]

configuration as follows

```
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size=1G
innodb_numa_interleave

innodb_buffer_pool_size=75G

key_buffer_size = 12G
max_allowed_packet = 16M
thread_stack = 192K
thread_cache_size = 8

tmp_table_size = 1024M
max_heap_table_size = 1024M
max_connections = 600
max_connect_errors = 10000

query_cache_limit = 1M
query_cache_size = 50M
```

htop: https://ibb.co/gwGSkc1 - (Before the issue)

iostat: https://ibb.co/YyJWkb9 - (Before the issue)

df -h : https://ibb.co/x25vg52

RAM 94G

CORE COUNT 32

SSD : /var/lib/mysql is mounted on a SSD Volume (Solution is hosted on open stack)

GLOBAL STATUS : https://pastebin.com/yC4FUYiE

GLOBAL Variables :  https://pastebin.com/PfsYTRbm

PROCESS LIST : https://pastebin.com/TyA5KBDb

Comment: [sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) should be at (max) 80% of physical memory, does this apply in your situation?  And what about [sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances), and other relevant settings?

Comment: physical memory is 90 GB so buffer pool size is ok I assume. sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances is default value. Could you advice if this should be changed from the default value? (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances) 8 as per the documentation

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.Consider 10 max_connect_errors.

Comment: @WilsonHauck: Please find the information below
RAM 94G
CORE COUNT 32
SSD : /var/lib/mysql is mounted on a SSD Volume (Solution is hosted on open stack)
GLOBAL STATUS : https://pastebin.com/yC4FUYiE
GLOBAL Variables : https://pastebin.com/PfsYTRbm
PROCESS LIST : https://pastebin.com/TyA5KBDb
I will add the screens of htop and iostats to the description itself

Answer (score 1):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function
innodb_io_capacity=1500  # from 200 to use more of your available SSD IOPS
read_rnd_buffer_size=128K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 474,918
key_buffer_size=16M  # from 12G less than 1% used and your max is 94G available.
```

For additional suggestions view profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.

There are many more opportunities to improve your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Not much exciting in the settings:

```
  Analysis of GLOBAL STATUS and VARIABLES:
```

**Observations:**

- Version: 5.7.31
- 94 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 17:36:15; some GLOBAL STATUS values may not be meaningful yet.
- You are not running on Windows.
- Running 64-bit version
- You appear to be running entirely (or mostly) InnoDB.

**The More Important Issues:**

MyISAM is not used, so key_buffer_size = 12G is a waste of RAM.  Change to 50M.

If you have SSD drives, increase `innodb_io_capacity` from 200 to 1000.

Several metrics point to inefficient queries.  They may need better indexes or rewriting.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

**Details and other observations:**

`( key_buffer_size ) = 12,288M / 96256M = 12.8%` -- % of RAM used for key_buffer (for MyISAM indexes)
-- 20% is ok if you are not using InnoDB.

`( (key_buffer_size - 1.2 * Key_blocks_used * 1024) ) = ((12288M - 1.2 * 9 * 1024)) / 96256M = 12.8%` -- Percent of RAM wasted in key_buffer.
-- Decrease key_buffer_size (now 12884901888).

`( Key_blocks_used * 1024 / key_buffer_size ) = 9 * 1024 / 12288M = 0.00%` -- Percent of key_buffer used. High-water-mark.
-- Lower key_buffer_size (now 12884901888) to avoid unnecessary memory usage.

`( (key_buffer_size / 0.20 + innodb_buffer_pool_size / 0.70) ) = ((12288M / 0.20 + 76800M / 0.70)) / 96256M = 177.8%` -- Most of available ram should be made available for caching.
-- http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth * innodb_page_cleaners ) = 1,024 * 4 = 4,096` -- Amount of work for page cleaners every second.
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixable by lowering lru_scan_depth: Consider 1000 / innodb_page_cleaners (now 4). Also check for swapping.

`( innodb_page_cleaners / innodb_buffer_pool_instances ) = 4 / 8 = 0.5` -- innodb_page_cleaners
-- Recommend setting innodb_page_cleaners (now 4) to innodb_buffer_pool_instances (now 8)
(Beginning to go away in 10.5)

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth ) = 1,024`
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixed by lowering lru_scan_depth

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free / Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total ) = 1,579,794 / 4914600 = 32.1%` -- Pct of buffer_pool currently not in use
-- innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 80530636800) is bigger than necessary?

`( innodb_io_capacity_max / innodb_io_capacity ) = 2,000 / 200 = 10` -- Capacity: max/plain
-- Recommend 2. Max should be about equal to the IOPs your I/O subsystem can handle. (If the drive type is unknown 2000/200 may be a reasonable pair.)

`( Innodb_os_log_written / (Uptime / 3600) / innodb_log_files_in_group / innodb_log_file_size ) = 138,870,272 / (63375 / 3600) / 2 / 1024M = 0.00367` -- Ratio
-- (see minutes)

`( Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written ) = 63,375 / 60 * 1024M / 138870272 = 8,166` -- Minutes between InnoDB log rotations Beginning with 5.6.8, this can be changed dynamically; be sure to also change my.cnf.
-- (The recommendation of 60 minutes between rotations is somewhat arbitrary.) Adjust innodb_log_file_size (now 1073741824). (Cannot change in AWS.)

`( innodb_flush_method ) = innodb_flush_method = O_DSYNC` -- How InnoDB should ask the OS to write blocks. Suggest O_DIRECT or O_ALL_DIRECT (Percona) to avoid double buffering. (At least for Unix.) See chrischandler for caveat about O_ALL_DIRECT

`( innodb_flush_neighbors ) = 1` -- A minor optimization when writing blocks to disk.
-- Use 0 for SSD drives; 1 for HDD.

`( innodb_io_capacity ) = 200` -- I/O ops per second capable on disk . 100 for slow drives; 200 for spinning drives; 1000-2000 for SSDs; multiply by RAID factor.

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( min( tmp_table_size, max_heap_table_size ) ) = (min( 1024M, 1024M )) / 96256M = 1.1%` -- Percent of RAM to allocate when needing MEMORY table (per table), or temp table inside a SELECT (per temp table per some SELECTs). Too high may lead to swapping.
-- Decrease tmp_table_size (now 1073741824) and max_heap_table_size (now 1073741824) to, say, 1% of ram.

`( character_set_server ) = character_set_server = latin1`
-- Charset problems may be helped by setting character_set_server (now latin1) to utf8mb4. That is the future default.

`( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile (now ON) = ON is a potential security issue

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables / Created_tmp_tables ) = 59,659 / 68013 = 87.7%` -- Percent of temp tables that spilled to disk
-- Check slowlog

`( tmp_table_size ) = 1024M` -- Limit on size of *MEMORY* temp tables used to support a SELECT
-- Decrease tmp_table_size (now 1073741824) to avoid running out of RAM. Perhaps no more than 64M.

`( (Com_insert + Com_update + Com_delete + Com_replace) / Com_commit ) = (53844 + 35751 + 1 + 0) / 35789 = 2.5` -- Statements per Commit (assuming all InnoDB)
-- Low: Might help to group queries together in transactions; High: long transactions strain various things.

`( Select_range_check ) = 70,106 / 63375 = 1.1 /sec` -- no good index
-- Find slow queries; check indexes.

`( Select_scan ) = 2,393,389 / 63375 = 38 /sec` -- full table scans
-- Add indexes / optimize queries (unless they are tiny tables)

`( Select_scan / Com_select ) = 2,393,389 / 10449190 = 22.9%` -- % of selects doing full table scan. (May be fooled by Stored Routines.)
-- Add indexes / optimize queries

`( Sort_merge_passes ) = 18,868 / 63375 = 0.3 /sec` -- Heafty sorts
-- Increase sort_buffer_size (now 262144) and/or optimize complex queries.

`( slow_query_log ) = slow_query_log = OFF` -- Whether to log slow queries. (5.1.12)

`( long_query_time ) = 10` -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query.
-- Suggest 2

`( log_slow_slave_statements ) = log_slow_slave_statements = OFF` -- (5.6.11, 5.7.1) By default, replicated statements won't show up in the slowlog; this causes them to show.
-- It can be helpful in the slowlog to see writes that could be interfering with Replica reads.

`( Aborted_connects / Connections ) = 1,057 / 2070 = 51.1%` -- Perhaps a hacker is trying to break in? (Attempts to connect)

`( max_connect_errors ) = 10,000` -- A small protection against hackers.
-- Perhaps no more than 200.

You have the Query Cache half-off. You should set both query_cache_type = OFF and query_cache_size = 0 . There is (according to a rumor) a 'bug' in the QC code that leaves some code on unless you turn off both of those settings.

**Abnormally small:**

```
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs = 0
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size = 128MB
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size = 128MB
innodb_sort_buffer_size = 1.05e+6
```

**Abnormally large:**

```
(Com_select + Qcache_hits) / (Com_insert + Com_update + Com_delete + Com_replace) = 116
Com_create_procedure = 0.11 /HR
Com_drop_procedure = 0.11 /HR
Com_show_charsets = 0.68 /HR
Com_show_plugins = 0.11 /HR
Created_tmp_files = 0.6 /sec
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data = 838452 /sec
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data = 3.24e+6
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free = 1.58e+6
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total = 4.91e+6
Key_blocks_unused = 1.02e+7
Ssl_default_timeout = 7,200
Ssl_session_cache_misses = 10
Ssl_verify_depth = 1.84e+19
Ssl_verify_mode = 5
max_heap_table_size = 1024MB
min(max_heap_table_size, tmp_table_size) = 1024MB
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
ft_boolean_syntax = + -><()~*:&
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
innodb_numa_interleave = ON
optimizer_trace = enabled=off,one_line=off
optimizer_trace_features = greedy_search=on, range_optimizer=on, dynamic_range=on, repeated_subselect=on
slave_rows_search_algorithms = TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN
```